# What can be said about the derived functor of a composition between unbounded derived categories?

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories, derived-functors

Let $\mathcal A, \mathcal B,\mathcal C$ be abelian categories and let $F:\mathcal A \to \mathcal B,G: \mathcal B \to \mathcal C$ be left exact functors such that $RF:D(\mathcal A) \to D(\mathcal B), RG:D(\mathcal B) \to D(\mathcal C)$ exist. What are some sufficient conditions so that we can say something interesting on the existence of $R(G \circ F):D(\mathcal A) \to D(\mathcal C)$ and its relation to $RF$ and $RG$?

Comment: The hypotheses of the Grothendieck spectral sequence suffice https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_spectral_sequence?wprov=sfti1

Comment: @FernandoMuro For unbounded derived categories, you need something more. For instance, if the abelian categories $B$ and $C$ are generated by objects of finite cohomological dimension, all is good. More generally, it suffices that the limit of the Postnikov tower of each complex converges to the given complex.

Comment: @D.-C.Cisinski Do we have to assume the abelian categories to be Grothendieck so that the unbounded derived category defined by Bousfield localization would be well-behaved? Seemingly this implies that right Kan extensions are absolute.

Comment: @D.-C. Cisinki: in which sense should the Postnikov tower converge? On finite pieces it does, so what sense of convergence do you mean?

Comment: @Echo in the sense that the canonical map to the homotopy limit of the tower is an isomorphism, I presume.

Comment: About the relation between $R(G\circ F)$ and $RG\circ RF$, there's Tag [015M](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/015M) of the Stacks Project.

Comment: @ElíasGuisadoVillalgordo the stacks project link you gave me only talks about the bounded derived categories.

Comment: @LukasHeger My bad. No idea then, sorry :/